# How to configure Synology to use only standard HTTP ports 80 and 443 instead of 5000

Tags: http, synology

I want to reconfigure a Synology running latest DSM 5 to work on normal HTTP ports.

The default configuration is to use port 5000 and 5001 for HTTPS and I do not like these because they are quite often blocked by most firewalls (in addition to the accessibility and visual aspects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change this in your DSM Control Panel. Under Connectivity > Network > DSM Settings you can set the ports.

[image: Setting DSM ports]

Obviously, make sure that if you have another webserver running on your NAS like Apache, it doesn't listen on those ports.

Comment: When I do this i get an error message that this port is used

Comment: @Dennkster If you already have something like Apache or nginx installed on your NAS, those are most likely to have "claimed" that port already. You can only run one service on a port at a time.